# ASP.NET 2.0 Cannot compileeand debug on win10?

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms

I've encountered a problem about windows upgrade.
Here are two kinds of developing environment.

1. windows7  64 bits + vs2005 + Framework 2.0 + SDK 2.0
2. **windows10 64 bits** + vs2005 + Framework 2.0 + SDK 2.0

Option 1 works fine, but 2 cannot compile and debug with the same project

Did anyone have this problem like I do ?

Comment: What error you get while working on Windows 10?

Comment: It said that the project can't find "add" object (or define) in web.config (and more basic items like that)

Comment: But I tried to force uninstall .NET framework 3.5 in win 10, then reinstall all software all-over again,  It works fine...